# Why doesn't this clojure code using go blocks work?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, macros, lisp, s-expression

```
(defn ff [t]
  (let [ch (chan 5)]
    (map (fn [i]
          (println i)) t)
    (go (>! ch 0))))

(ff [1 2 3 4 5])
```

The mapping function body isn't being executed. If I remove the go block in the last line, it works as expected.

This function gives the same problem:

```
(defn ff [t]
  (let [ch (chan 5)]
    (map (fn [i]
          (println i)) t)
    (>!! ch 0)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) runs lazily.

When it's not the last form in the let block, the result isn't being evaluated, so the mapping function doesn't get executed.

This'd happen without the `go` blocks.

If you explicitly want to evaluate a sequence for side-effects (like `println`), use [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq). If you need a lazy sequence to be evaluated eagerly (e.g. it depends on a network connection that will close), wrap it in [`doall`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall)